# How to use Rails 5's ActiveRecord attributes to provide a virtual column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I want to add virtual columns to some of my models, but to have their values returned by ActiveRecord statements like `Product.first`, so that I can use statements like `Product.first.to_json` to output the product, with the virtual columns, on an API request.

The values of the columns depend on other model attributes. I *don't* want these columns persisted to the database.

I tried this:

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  def total
    price + tax
  end
end
```

but `Product.first` did not include the total.

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :total, :decimal, default: -> { 0.0 }
end
```

adds a `total: 0.0` to the returned object, but

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :total, :decimal, default: -> { price + tax }
end
```

fails with messages such as

```
#<NameError: undefined local variable or method `price' for #<Class:0x0000557b51c2c960>>
```

and

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :total, :decimal, default: -> { 0.0 }

  def total
    price + tax
  end
end
```

still returns `total: 0.0`.

I'm not even sure if `attribute` is the right way to do this, as the docs seem to imply that it binds to a column.

To sum up:

- the `products` table should not contain a `total` column.
- accessing `Product` through ActiveRecord should return a `Product` object that includes a `total` key with a computed value based on other attributes of the model.

Is this even possible?

I *really* don't want to have to replace every `to_json` call with a lot of code manually inserting these virtual columns…

Comment: Do you use ActiveModelSerializers in your project? If yes, you can just create a separate serializer with `total` method and use it in needed controller actions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `as_json` in your model to include your method.

This won't include total in your retrieved Product object, but it will include it when calling `.to_json` on the object.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :total, :decimal, default: -> { 0.0 }

  def total
    price + tax
  end

  def as_json(options = {})
    super(methods: [:total])
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks — this seems like the cleanest way of doing this, as it keeps everything in the model.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `methods` option

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  def total
    price + tax
  end
end

Product.first.to_json(methods: :total)
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that still involves changing every `to_json` call to add the methods. I was hoping to get the same result as using `attribute` where it comes back when the model is accessed as an integral part of it — just not written to the database.

Comment: @JohnY Or you could override `to_json` and add the `:methods` yourself. You'd need to be careful to properly handle a `:methods` supplied from the outside of course.

Answer (score 1):

A [virtual/generated column](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/65bf1c60053e727835e06392d27a2fb49665484c) (assuming [MySQL](https://gabi.dev/2016/10/17/understanding-generated-columns/)/[MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/)) in your database would solve what you need. Because it is generated from data from other columns, you can't write to it and it is only updated during read operations. There is the option to persist the data, but that's not the question here.

In my example, I want to add a virtual column "age" to my People database that is the difference between person.birthday and curdate().
I generate the column:

```
rails generate migration AddAgeToPeople age:virtual
```

Then I edit the migration file so that `add_column :people, :age, :virtual`
 becomes

```
class AddAgeToPeople < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :people, :age, :int, as: "timestampdiff(year, birthday, curdate())"
  end
end
```

The end result would be SQL that looks like:

`ALTER TABLE people ADD COLUMN age GENERATED ALWAYS AS (timestampdiff(year, birthday, curdate()));`

`| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra             |
| age          | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    | VIRTUAL GENERATED |`

The end result is an attribute in the model that I can interact with normally (read only though)

Comment: Thanks, but I did say I didn't want that virtual in the database, just the model :)